# Show that the solution of an initial value problem is always less than a given constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

[image]

My try is that

$$\frac{dy}{dt} =(y-3)e^{\cos ty}$$

$$\frac{dy}{y-3}= e^{\cos ty}dt$$

$$\ln (y-3)=-\frac{e^{\cos ty}}{\sin ty} +c$$

my steps is correct or I made mistakes ? please help to solve this problem

Comment: This does not look at all simple. The 2nd/3rd lines of your try are wrong. The rhs should be integrated wrt $t$, so the $y$ terms should be on the lhs, which is not then so easy. Are you sure you have got the question correctly stated?

Comment: I took print screen for the question as you see

Comment: Anyway, someone else has now given you a useful hint!

Comment: Generally, when you are asked to show that the solution satisfies some inequality, or tends to a particular number, your first impulse should **not** be "let's solve the equation". You are being asked to investigate *qualitative* nature of the solution, which **does not** require having a formula for it. 

This ODE is intentionally made messy so that finding an explicit solution is a hopeless task.  Following Robert Israel's hint is the way to go.

Comment: @Thursday. That is excellent advice!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $y=3$ is a solution of the DE.  Use the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct answer

[image]

Comment: In the equation, you have $\cos(ty)$, not $\cos(t)$. No, your argument does not achieve the goal. Instead you should argue by contradiction; suppose $y(t_1)\ge 3$ for some $t_1$. Then $y(t_2)=3$ for some $t_2\le t_1$. Then use the uniqueness for IVP.